# added Standardscaler but receive errors in Cross Validation and the correlation matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation, pearson-correlation

This is the code I built to apply a multiple linear regression. I added standard scaler to fix the Y intercept p-value which was not significant but the problem that the results of CV RMSE in the end changed and have nosense anymore and received an error in the code for plotting the correlation Matrix saying : AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'corr'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr


# Import Excel File
data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\AchourAh\\Desktop\\Multiple_Linear_Regression\\SP Level Reasons Excels\\SP000273701_PL14_IPC_03_09_2018_Reasons.xlsx",'Sheet1') #Import Excel file

# Replace null values of the whole dataset with 0
data1 = data.fillna(0)
print(data1)

# Extraction of the independent and dependent variables
X = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]] #Extract the column of the COPCOR SP we are going to check its impact
Y = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),9] #Extract the column of the PAUS SP

# Data Splitting to train and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size =0.25,random_state=1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
ss = StandardScaler()
X_train = ss.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = ss.transform(X_test)

# Statistical Analysis of the training set with Statsmodels
X = sm.add_constant(X_train) # add a constant to the model
est = sm.OLS(Y_train, X).fit()
print(est.summary()) # print the results

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import math
lm = LinearRegression()  # create an lm object of LinearRegression Class
lm.fit(X_train,Y_train)  # train our LinearRegression model using the training set of data - dependent and independent variables as parameters. Teaching lm that Y_train values are all corresponding to X_train.
print(lm.intercept_)
print(lm.coef_)
mse_test = mean_squared_error(Y_test, lm.predict(X_test))
print(math.sqrt(mse_test))

# Data Splitting to train and test set of the reduced data
X_1 = data1.iloc[0:len(data1),[1,2]] #Extract the column of the COPCOR SP we are going to check its impact
X_train2, X_test2, Y_train2, Y_test2 = train_test_split(X_1, Y, test_size =0.25,random_state=1)
X_train2 = ss.fit_transform(X_train2)
X_test2 = ss.transform(X_test2)

# Statistical Analysis of the reduced model with Statsmodels
X_reduced = sm.add_constant(X_train2) # add a constant to the model
est_reduced = sm.OLS(Y_train2, X_reduced).fit()
print(est_reduced.summary()) # print the results

# Fitting a Linear Model for the reduced model with Scikit-Learn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import math
lm1 = LinearRegression() #create an lm object of LinearRegression Class
lm1.fit(X_train2, Y_train2)
print(lm1.intercept_)
print(lm1.coef_)
mse_test1 = mean_squared_error(Y_test2, lm1.predict(X_test2))
print(math.sqrt(mse_test1))

#Cross Validation and Training again the model
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn import model_selection
kf = KFold(n_splits=6, random_state=1)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X_train2):
 print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
 X_train1, X_test1 = X[train_index], X[test_index]
 Y_train1, Y_test1 = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
results = -1 * model_selection.cross_val_score(lm1, X_train1, Y_train1,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kf)
print(np.sqrt(results))
#RMSE values interpretation
print(math.sqrt(mse_test1))
print(math.sqrt(results.mean()))
#Good model built no overfitting or underfitting (Barely Same for test and training :Goal of Cross validation but low prediction accuracy = Value is big

import seaborn
Corr=X_train2.corr(method='pearson')
mask=np.zeros_like(Corr)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)]=True
seaborn.heatmap(Corr,cmap='RdYlGn_r',vmax=1.0,vmin=-1.0,mask=mask, linewidths=2.5)
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
enter code here
```

Do you have an idea how to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem lies with:

```
Corr=X_train2.corr(method='pearson')
```

.corr is a pandas dataframe method but X_train2 is a numpy array at that stage. If a dataframe/series is passed into StandardScaler, a numpy array is returned. Try replacing the above with:

```
Corr=pd.DataFrame(X_train2).corr(method='pearson')
```

or make use of numpy.corrcoef or numpy.correlate in their respective forms.